# Is there anyway Nodes can be re-ordered or removed relative to an element node using Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

In the following I would like to order the `<table>..</table>` node according to the input (`inputY`, `inputX` in this case) in `id` attribute or remove `<table>..</table>` if only one input is sent. How can I achieve it using DOM parser.

```xml
<employees>
    <table>
        <employee>
            <id attr="inputY">
                <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
                <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
                <department>
                    <id>101</id>
                    <name>IT</name>
                </department>
            </id>
        </employee>
    </table>
    <table>
        <employee>
            <id attr="inputX">
                <firstName>Brian</firstName>
                <lastName>Schultz</lastName>
                <department>
                    <id>102</id>
                    <name>HR</name>
                </department>
            </id>
        </employee>
    </table>
<employees>
```

If input is passed in the order of `inputX` and `inputY` then the XML would be like the following :

```xml
<employees>
    <table>
        <employee>
            <id attr="inputX">
                <firstName>Brian</firstName>
                <lastName>Schultz</lastName>
                <department>
                    <id>102</id>
                    <name>HR</name>
                </department>
            </id>
        </employee>
    </table>
    <table>
        <employee>
            <id attr="inputY">
                <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
                <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
                <department>
                    <id>101</id>
                    <name>IT</name>
                </department>
            </id>
        </employee>
    </table>
<employees>
```

This is what I have done so far :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().
            newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse("src/main/resources/some1.xml");
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    ids.add("inputY");
    ids.add("inputX");
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    Node employees = root.getElementsByTagName("employees").item(0);
    NodeList moveList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for (int k = 0; k < moveList.getLength(); k++) {
        System.out.println(moveList.item(k));
        Node move = moveList.item(k);
        Element eMove = (Element) move;
        NodeList idList = eMove.getElementsByTagName("id");
        for (int i = 0; i < idList.getLength(); i++) {
            if (i < ids.size()) {
                boolean result = ids.contains(
                        idList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).
                                getNodeValue());
                if (result) {
                    //System.out.println("parent node : " + move.getParentNode().getFirstChild());
                    Node currentFirstNode = employees.getFirstChild();
                    Node copyNode = move.cloneNode(true);
                    Node placeholder = currentFirstNode.getParentNode();
                    placeholder.insertBefore(copyNode,currentFirstNode);
                    placeholder.removeChild(move);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:

Here is my new code: Still it fails to order the nodes properly.  node with attribute inputX comes before inputZ, even though I have inputZ before input X in the list. Any suggestion?

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().
                newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse("src/main/resources/some1.xml");
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
        ids.add("inputZ");
        ids.add("inputX");
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Node employees = root.getElementsByTagName("employees").item(0);
        NodeList moveList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
        for (int k = 0; k < moveList.getLength(); k++) {
            System.out.println("# of table nodes : " + moveList.getLength());
            Node move = moveList.item(k);
            Element eMove = (Element) move;
            NodeList idList = eMove.getElementsByTagName("id");
                System.out.println("id attribute : " + idList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0));
                    boolean result = ids.contains(
                            idList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).
                                    getNodeValue());
                    if (result) {
                        System.out.println(result);
                        Node currentFirstNode = employees.getFirstChild();
                        Node placeholder = currentFirstNode.getParentNode();
                        placeholder.insertBefore(move, currentFirstNode);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(result);
                        System.out.println("Employees child node : " + employees.getChildNodes());
                        employees.removeChild(move);
                    }
        }
```

XML :

```
<root>
    <employees>
        <table>
            <employee>
                <id attr="inputZ">
                    <firstName>Ben</firstName>
                    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
                    <department>
                        <id>103</id>
                        <name>Business</name>
                    </department>
                </id>
            </employee>
        </table>
        <table>
            <employee>
                <id attr="inputX">
                    <firstName>Brian</firstName>
                    <lastName>Schultz</lastName>
                    <department>
                        <id>102</id>
                        <name>HR</name>
                    </department>
                </id>
            </employee>
        </table>
        <table>
            <employee>
                <id attr="inputY">
                    <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
                    <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
                    <department>
                        <id>101</id>
                        <name>IT</name>
                    </department>
                </id>
            </employee>
        </table>
    </employees>
</root>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried parsing with DOM yet? What part of using [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) methods to modify the structure is troubling you? `removeChild(Node oldChild)`, `appendChild(Node newChild)`, and `insertBefore(Node newChild, Node refChild)` all seem pretty self-evident for this task.

Comment: @Andreas, I have updated the question with what I have tried. Basically, I am trying to clone the node and put it before the first node and delete its actual entry. This is because I am also updating the value of lets say in this example firstName. I am trying to order the xml in the order of the attribute (attr) I am receiving.

Comment: Why clone node? Just remove it and re-insert where you want it to be, i.e. *move* it. Actually, removing is optional, since inserting will auto-remove it from the old location in the tree.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there are no `<employees>` element below the root element. The root element *is* the `<employees>` element.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for pointing out that I dont need to clone or remove nodes. However, I am still not able to order the nodes properly. I have added the updated code.

Comment: Really? I already [gave you code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61037898/5221149) to do it.

Comment: In Update 2, why are you indenting the code weirdly like that? --- You should not read attributes by position. `getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue()` should be `getAttribute("attr")`. --- `moveList` lists the `<table>` nodes in the order they are found in the XML, so calling `insertBefore(move, currentFirstNode)` will move the elements up front, in effect reversing the order. Where in the code do you believe the order of values in `ids` means anything?

Comment: @Andreas, apologies, I didn't see the solution you provided below. I was following your 2nd comment "inserting will auto-remove it from the old location in the tree". In the code, I defined the ArrayList of ids (actually it is the list of id's attribute), that is <table> node order I wanted in the resulting XML to be. If there are "n" numbers of <table> nodes, then the elements in the arraylist <= n.

Comment: I know what `ids` is and what you intend it to represent. I was just asking where in *your* code you believed you had written code where the order of values in the list affected the outcome.

Comment: How should edge cases be handled? 1) You said to remove `<table>` element if only one is present, correct? 2) What if `ids` has 5 values, but only 3 `<table>` elements are present? Incomplete set means remove them all? 3) Can `ids` list same name more than once? 4) If not, what if multiple `<table>` elements with same id is present? Keep the first, remove the rest? 5) What if root element has child elements other than `<table>` elements? Remove them? If not, how to order `<table>` elements?

Comment: @Andreas, thank you for response/questions.
1) that is in case if there are only 2 <table> elements
2) ids cannot be greater than the number of <table> elements
3)No, ids needs to be unique
4)ids are unique and cannot be repeated
5)Inside <root> element (in update 2) there could be multiple child nodes and not removing them, but inside <employees> node there can only be <table> nodes. My thinking was to creating a list of <table> nodes inside <employees> node and loop to find the id attribute (attr) and order them  according to the id elements present in ArrayList<String> ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Load XML file into DOM tree and verify root element name
        Element root = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse("test.xml")
                .getDocumentElement();
        if (! root.getTagName().equals("employees"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid root element name: " + root.getTagName());

        // Locate all <table> elements, identify "inputX" and "inputY" tables, and their relative order
        boolean inputYBeforeInputX = false;
        Node inputX = null, inputY = null;
        List<Node> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Node child = root.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.getNodeName().equals("table")) {
                String id = getFirstChildByTagName(child, "employee")
                        .flatMap(e -> getFirstChildByTagName(e, "id"))
                        .map(e -> e.getAttribute("attr"))
                        .orElse(null);
                if (inputX == null && "inputX".equals(id)) {
                    inputX = child;
                } else if (inputY == null && "inputY".equals(id)) {
                    inputY = child;
                    inputYBeforeInputX = (inputX == null);
                } else {
                    toBeRemoved.add(child);
                }
            }
        }

        // If only one of "inputX" and "inputY" was found, mark it to be removed
        if (inputX != null && inputY == null)
            toBeRemoved.add(inputX);
        else if (inputY != null && inputX == null)
            toBeRemoved.add(inputY);

        // Remove superfluous <table> elements
        for (Node nodeToRemove : toBeRemoved)
            root.removeChild(nodeToRemove);

        // Swap "inputX" and "inputY" if "inputY" was before "inputX"
        if (inputYBeforeInputX && inputX != null && inputY != null) {
            if (inputY.getNextSibling() == inputX) {
                root.insertBefore(inputX, inputY);
            } else {
                Node inputXnext = inputX.getNextSibling();
                root.insertBefore(inputX, inputY.getNextSibling());
                root.insertBefore(inputY, inputXnext);
            }
        }

        // Print result XML
        TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                .newTransformer()
                .transform(new DOMSource(root), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
    private static Optional<Element> getFirstChildByTagName(Node parent, String tagName) {
        for (Node child = parent.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling())
            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.getNodeName().equals(tagName))
                return Optional.of((Element) child);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "using Java", but by far the easiest way to do this sort of thing is using XSLT, and of course that can easily be invoked from Java.

This one can be done easily enough even in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <employees>
    <xsl:for-each select="employees/table">
      <xsl:sort select="employee/id/@attr">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </employees>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by this part of the requirement: "or remove .. if only one input is sent".

Comment: Key Thank you. Actually, I am using Java DOM Parser. The second requirement is, when only one input is given.. for example inputX is the only input then <table></table> that contains element with attribute inputY should be deleted.

Comment: After fixing syntax errors, that XSLT still doesn't work. Result of applying it: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><employees/>`

Comment: Corrected. I still don't understand the other part of the requirement. If inputX is the only input then how can you delete inputY?

Comment: @MichaelKay as I updated with what I have tried, if there are n number of <id attr={x}> nodes (nodeList), and only 2 attriubtes (ids) are provided, then the resulting xml should only have 2 <id attr={y}> nodes. I do not yet have else condition as I am struggling to move the ones matched in order.

Comment: @MichaelKay *"Corrected."* What has been corrected? The answer hasn't been changed. Nothing has been corrected.

Comment: For some reason my edits weren't applied. Trying again.